# How to check key frame from android mediacodec when decoding

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Can we check whether a frame is a key frame when decoding using mediacodec?

I've already tried `MediaCodec.BufferInfo.flags & BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME`, but as the doc says, it's for encoding.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to check the NALU's header code before passing it to the decoder :

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x67 -> SPS 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x68 -> PPS 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x65 -> I-frame (Key frame) 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x21 -> P-frame
```